# Promise function in separate file

Tags: javascript, express, promise

I could get this function to work in one file, but I'd like to keep things clean by separating into multiple files.

```
// library.js file
module.exports = {
    get: () =>{
        return new Promise((reject, resolve) =>{
            return resolve(https.get('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=' + cred.access_token, (res) =>{
                res.setEncoding('utf8');
                return res.on('data', (data) =>{
                    return data;
                });
            }));
        });
    }
}
```

I tried logging this but it didn't show anything?

```
// server.js file
igLib.get().then((data) => {
    console.log("testing: " + data);
})
```

However, if I just do a simple log of..

```
// server.js file
console.log(igLib.get());
```

I somehow get the data without the `res.setEncoding('utf8')`.

Any tips on what to do?

**Update:**
I couldn't get the promise to work and I'm sorry to the folks who provided me good answers to my problem, but I went ahead and used the request-promise module instead. This is how it looks like:

```
// library.js file
var instagramSelfUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=' + cred.access_token;

module.exports = {
    get: () =>{
        return rp(instagramSelfUrl).then((res) =>{
            return res;
        });
    }
}
```

And here is where I console.log:

```
// server.js file
    igLib.get().then((data) =>{
    console.log(data);
});
```

It's simpler and it works. If there's a solution to the problem other than using a module for this to work, please let it be known and post! Thank you all to who posted and helped out!

Comment: separate files ! hmmmm why not use js classes then

Comment: @user889030 What do files have to do with classes?!

Comment: Your problem is that you immediately resolve your promise with the return value from `https.get` (which is `undefined`), instead of resolving with the `data` inside the asynchronous callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The promise you create should resolve with the data from the response.

```
// library.js file
const https = require('https');
const instagramSelfUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=' + cred.access_token;

module.exports = {
    get: () => new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        https.get(instagramSelfUrl, res => {
            var chunks = [];
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            res.on('data', chunk => chunks.push(chunk));
            res.on('end', () => resolve(chunks.join('')));
        });
    })
};
```

In fact, the above is incomplete and brittle. For example, request errors or response status 500 should reject the promise, but there is no error handling. Or when the response is not really UTF-8 it will decode the data improperly. And those are only the two most obvious issues here.

The promisification of HTTP requests is a solved problem. I strongly suggest that you use [one of the available libraries](https://github.com/request/request-promise) instead of rolling your own code that makes all the mistakes all over again.

```
const request = require('request-promise');
const instagramSelfUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=' + cred.access_token;

module.exports = {
    get: () => request(instagramSelfUrl)
};
```

Now the function is complete and behaves properly, even in corner cases. It also is so short that it hardly justifies writing a separate function at all.

Comment: I didn't realize you can us resolve as a call back. I'll test this out, thank you. And yes I understand how brittle the function is: Still trying my hand on promises =\

Comment: `function (x) { f(x) }` and its fat-arrow cousin  `x => f(x)` are semantically equivalent to just `f`. Whether `f` is `resolve` or any other function makes no difference at all. it's all just functions calling each other. Making a function that does nothing but wrap another function is superfluous most of the time.

Comment: I still couldn't get the promise to work, but I just decided to go ahead and use the request-promise module. And yes I understand, I just didn't realize that you can completely replace a callback function with resolve in its place. Couldn't get it to work in the end. Thank you though!

Comment: @Edrich Yeah, the https module so low-level, you actually need to handle the data chunks that arrive individually. See changed answer. Forgot about that myself, which kind of proves my point. Rolling your own HTTP library is just not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you aren't return the data correctly try this:

```
// library.js file
module.exports = {
    get: () =>{
        return new Promise((reject, resolve) =>{
            https.get('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=' + cred.access_token, (res) =>{
                res.setEncoding('utf8');
                return res.on('data', (data) =>{
                    return resolve(data);
                });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to `return` the result from `on` or `resolve`.

Comment: I've actually tried this before as well but my console.log doesn't even get hit in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
module.exports = {
    get: () =>{
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
            https.get('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=' + cred.access_token, (res) =>{
                res.setEncoding('utf8');
                res.on('data', (data) =>{
                    resolve(data);
                });
            }).on('error', (e) => reject(e))
        });
    }
}
```

For more on promise you can visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: I've tried this, but my console.log doesn't even get hit in the other file.